# Can't format an USB Drive

Tags: disk-utility

I receive following Error in disk-utility:

```
Error synchronizing after initial wipe: Timed out waiting for object (udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

Comment: What options did you chose?

Comment: @Tim I've tried fast and slow, and both available partitions.

Comment: Have you installed `gparted` and tried it?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using gparted?

`sudo apt-get install gparted`

Open Gparted

`sudo gparted`

In the top right select your usb drive, it will probably be sdb, right click in the main window and unmount if needed.  Right click again and select delete and than right click one last time on the unallocated space and select new.  Now you just need to setup the USB partition to suit your needs.

If you still are having issues using gparted, you could always zero fill the drive, meaning, cleaning the drive completely by writing all zeros.

`sudo fdisk -l`

look for the sdX location for your USB stick.

`dd=if/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX`

This can take awhile depending on the size of your USB stick and your PC speed, etc...  Don't worry if you see a blinking cursor, just give it time, I did a 2gig mp3 player and it took about an hour and a half.

Now open gparted or disk utility and see if the drive is performing correctly.

Comment: I didn't quite understand your command `sudo fdisk -l


dd=if/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX ` but gparted did work.

Comment: you would use those commands in the terminal shell just as I typed them.  Your usb is most likely sdb so in terminal type sudo dd=if/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb.  this will clean your usb stick with all zeros, kind of a mega format.  Great tool for damaged disk spaces

Comment: I was more interested in the meaning of the commands. Also of `sudo fdisk-l`